# Spring security AJAX login not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement AJAX login. Here is my `spring-security.xml`

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login />
</http>

<beans:bean id="pwdEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="appUserDetailService" class="com.mobapp.security.AppUserDetailService"></beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="appUserDetailService">
        <password-encoder ref="pwdEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

instance initializer.xml

```
<bean id="instanceInitializer" class="com.mobapp.appinstances.AppInstances" destroy-method="shutDownInstances">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
          <value>127.0.0.1</value>
        </array>            
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="int">
        <value>9300</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Here is applicationContext

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mobapp.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
<bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="com.mobapp.security.LoginSuccessHandler"></bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<task:annotation-driven />       
<import resource="spring/instanceInitializer.xml"/>
<import resource="spring/security-context.xml"/>
```

Here userdetailsservice implementation

```
@Service

public class AppUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppUserDetailService.class);    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginUserName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));    
        System.out.println("inside load user by user name ........++++++++");
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);            

        return new LoggedInUser("test", passwordEncoder.encode("123"), true,true,true,true,authList);

    }

}
```

Here is Login controller

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);    

   @Autowired
   private  AppInstances appInstances;

   @Autowired
   AppUserDetailService appUserDetails;   

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/signup")
   public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody SignupForm form) throws Exception
   {
       ResponseEntity<?> validate = FormFieldValidator.validate(form);
       if(validate.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK)
           return validate;
       else
       {
           return SignupService.signup(form, appInstances);
       }
   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/login")
   public ResponseEntity<?> login()
   {
       UserDetails loadUserByUsername = appUserDetails.loadUserByUsername("test");
       logger.info("loadUserByUsername ========= "+loadUserByUsername);
       return new ResponseEntity("Hello",HttpStatus.OK);
   }   
}
```

Here the `logger.info` never get called.

Here is my login form

```
        <form id="loginForm" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your email" name='j_username'>
            <input type="password" size="10" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name='j_password'>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
        </form>


        $.ajax({
            url:"${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/login",
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {xhr.setRequestHeader($("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content"), $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"));},
            data:{j_username:$("#loginForm :input[name=j_username]").val(),j_password:$("#loginForm :input[name=j_password]").val()}
        }).done(function(d){
            alert("OK : "+d);
        }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Error: "+textStatus);
        });
```

LoggedInUSer.java

```
public class LoggedInUser extends User{

    private String name;
    private String userId;
    private String userName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public boolean isBlock() {
        return block;
    }
    private boolean block;

    public LoggedInUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {         
         super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
         //super(username, password, authorities);
         this.name = name;
         this.userId = userId;
         this.userName=userName;
         this.block=block;
    }
}
```

Whenever i enter `username`: `test` and `password` : `123` i got

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
Reason: Bad credentials
```

as response. What i am missing ?

Here is full log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9pquofzd_JYTlVPZ3ZvRF83S1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears this is an artificial setup. Your configuration states it is using <form-login /> which means Spring Security will generate the log in form for you rather than sending you to a custom log in form that supports AJAX. Can you try with Spring Security's default log in page and see if that works for you? Also, what do your logs look like? Does it reach your custom UserDetailsService?

Comment: When i enter `test` & `123` in the  response i get a Login form and on server side `nside load user by user name ........` line got printed

Comment: Please provide all the debug logs. Also please provide the complete LoggedInUser implementation.

Comment: updated my question..inside controller the `logger.info("loadUserByUsername ========= "+loadUserByUsername);` never get called.

Comment: This did not resolve my requests. Please include the entire debug logs. Please also include the complete LoggedInUser implementation. Also please ensure you are including the actual code and configuration as it looks like it is different making it quite difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: I updated with all full code and also attached full log file

Comment: Please include debug logs from Spring Security processing the request.

Comment: I have posted all debug log of my app

Answer (score 0):

Based on the incomplete logs provided by you (as indicated by Rob who is the Project Lead for Spring Security and would have been the best person on Earth to help you out!), a few things:

1. You are using Spring Security 4.0.1 with `<form-login>`: The Bad credentials is because SS 4+ will look for attribute names as 'username' & 'password' but you are providing 'j_username' & 'j_password' instead. At that time only,
2. Your logger.info never gets called: Rightly so. There is no reason it should get called! First up, whenever you make a POST request to /login, it will match with the default login processing URL in the spring security filter chain and you'll get Bad credentials. Secondly, it has a request method GET associated with it and whenever it will be requested directly, the default SS login page will appear (as it is provided by the DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter even before hitting your dispatcher.
3. You get a login form in response: Which is the expected behaviour here as SS is configured to use a login form.

If you still need some help, please provide the DEBUG log (set log4j log level to DEBUG; from your logger invocation it looks like you're using Log4J).